# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkUrlFactory

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to set timeout in retrofit

I added **compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.6.0'** to set timeout in Retrofit

application is crashing and showing error

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkUrlFactory**

here is my code

```
  Gson localGson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    this.uploadService = ((IndentSyncService)new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(URL)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(localGson))
            .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))//on this line app gets crash
            .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor()
            {
                public void intercept(RequestInterceptor.RequestFacade requestFacade)
                {
                    //By adding header to the request will allow us to debug into .Net code in server
                    if (URL.contains("10.0.2.2")) {
                        requestFacade.addHeader("Host", "localhost");
                    }
                }
            })
            .build().create(IndentSyncService.class));
```

my gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: Latest Retrofit is 2.3.0, latest OkHttp is 3.9.1. Retrofit 2 requires OkHttp 3. You're more likely to find help if you update your dependencies and code.

Comment: its already implemented now i want to add only timeout

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:1.6.0'
```

Source: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/879